# GridView ImageField With Text

Tags: asp.net, gridview, image

I have an ASP.Net GridView and I want to include an Image and a Text in the same field, something like this:

```
<a id="lnkForJQueryCall"><img src="whatever.png"> Some Other Number</a>
```

I have found the asp:ImageField does not have a Property for adding a text at right or left of the image, and there are no much options, is there any way to achieve it?

[EDIT] I was thinking of a css class workaround but have not figured out how to do it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`TemplateField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx) to display custom content in a data-bound control such as a `GridView`.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a id="lnkForJQueryCall"><img src="whatever.png"> Some Other Number</a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```